# How do I query all items of a specific types, in the Apollo client cache?

Tags: apollo, apollo-client

Is it possible to query for all items of a specific type in the apollo client cache? Our team is trying to adopt the Apollo cache to centralize state, and this question comes up. We have implemented almost all parts of this [tutorial](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/), but we are still unsure about the question.

Let's say that we this query, **someCollectionQuery**

```
someCollectionQuery {
  edges: {
    node: {
      factory {
        _id
        factoryName
      }
    }
  }
}
```

According to the documentation about [readQuery](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#readquery), we can now get all factories in the cache by doing:

```js
client.readQuery({
  query: someCollectionQuery,
});
```

We can do some simple iterations on the data and extract only the factories.

But this requires us to use the `someCollectionQuery`. What if other queries in the app also returned factories? Would it somehow be possible to create a *readQuery*, that returned all factories in the cache - regardless of what specific query that caused the factories to be in the cache in the first place? Something like:

```js
// How would you achieve something like this?
const allFactories = client.readByType('factory')
```